# XMLHttpRequest "Failed to load resource" with Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest

I try to get a data string with a XMLHttpRequest from a microcontroller.
The request works with Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome and Opera without any Errors in the Browser Konsole.
Only Safari makes problems with the ERROR "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost."
The microcontroller answers only with the data sting (5 Bytes).

```
function httpGetFreq(){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
            freq = parseFloat(xmlHttp.responseText) / 1000;
            animate ();
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.overrideMimeType('text/plain');
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "frequenz", true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Any information given in the network tab?

Comment: In the network tab  are the request with: Type: XHR; Method: GET; Scheme: HTTP; Status: -; Cached: No; Size: -; Transfered: -; Start Timer: 0.443ms; Latency: -; Duration -

Answer (score 0):

"**Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost**" might be due to one of the following reasons.

1. XHR requests a page with Content-Length > actual content length
   in this case Safari: waits until timeout, error event, "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost." in console
2. XHR requests  a page with Content-Length > actual content length ending in abrupt server termination
   Safari: error event, "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost." in console

So most probable reason might be content length mismatch, please check in wire-shark if content length recieved and sent is equal or if any packet is missing

Answer (score 0):

There could be one more possibility for this to happen. Browsers other than Safari ignore the response type, for example if you made a HTTP request and the response is a TCP packet. In this case Safari discards it, whereas other browsers like Chrome consider it as a HTTP response.

So check in your HTTP server code whether response has a HTTP header to it. From my view that must be the most probable reason for this. Check in Wireshark the response packet type whether it is HTTP or TCP.