# XHR not firing in Safari on Mac

Tags: networking, safari, xmlhttprequest

Recently I have been experiencing an issue where my XMLHttpRequests do not always get fired on first load. I am attempting to retrieve data from an internal url to a php page.

The error in *Network* tab is of **type** XHR **method** and **scheme** HTTPS all others (Status, Cached, Size, transferred, latency, duration) being a " - ".
Opening the resource of the given call simply has "An error occurred trying to load the resource." as expected.

Viewing the *Console* tab I am getting an error stating "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.".

After the page has loaded I am able to execute the JS manually in the console tab with success. I have tried forcing the event after document ready however this has had no effect on the given issue.

The worst part of all of this is that it isn't a consistent issue.

I have found some similar posts on stackoverflow but there doesn't seem to be a definite answer.
Hopefully these posts can also add some value to my query:

- [Safari AJAX bug - Failed to load resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434810/safari-ajax-bug-failed-to-load-resource)
- [XMLHttpRequest "Failed to load resource" with Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450778/xmlhttprequest-failed-to-load-resource-with-safari)
- [Javascript XHR onload function not firing on Safari for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731254/javascript-xhr-onload-function-not-firing-on-safari-for-the-first-time)

I do not personally own a mac and I am thus working off a colleague's some additional information I can provide is that it is
macOS Sierra version 10.12.6 and that the Safari version it is running is version 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7)

The issue ONLY happens on safari and no other browsers.
Hopefully my post contains sufficient information as this is my first stackoverflow post.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably caused by some weird interaction between:

- specific SSL/TLS certificates (most notably Let's Encrypt)
- Safari being the only major browser not supporting TLS session tickets (newer option for TLS session resumption)
- web server (TLS server) providing TLS session ids (older option for TLS session resumption), but not storing the actual session them and thus not actually allowing session resuming

Mitigation options:

- disabling keep-alive in HTTP (e.g. by responding with a "Connection: close" header), ideally only for Safari (check useragent)
- actually supporting TLS sessions (nginx: "ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m"; nodejs: implement newSession/resumeSession events)

Resources:

- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/apple-safari-browsers-fail-to-connect/3731/3
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3132

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue for css files not being loaded

> Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost

It was because of compression filter at the server side.
I disabled the compression filter for the content type and the issue got resolved.

Please share if you have solved the issue by any other means.